# Вопрос про наследование java

Tags: java

Почему в задаче, если сравнивать типы в приведенном порядке, то Лев и Тигр имеют тип Кот. Если же в методе строку "o instanceof Cat" сделать после аналогичных строк для Льва и Тигра, то программа работает корректно. Это как то связано с вызовом конструкторов наследуемых классов?

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getObjectType(new Cat()));
        System.out.println(getObjectType(new Tiger()));
        System.out.println(getObjectType(new Lion()));
        System.out.println(getObjectType(new Bull()));
        System.out.println(getObjectType(new Cow()));
        System.out.println(getObjectType(new Animal()));
    }

    public static String getObjectType(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Cat) return "Кот";
        else if (o instanceof Tiger) return "Тигр";
        else if (o instanceof Lion) return "Лев";
        else if (o instanceof Bull) return "Бык";
        else if (o instanceof Cow) return "Корова";
        else return "Животное";
    }

    public static class Cat extends Animal{
    }

    public static class Tiger extends Cat {
    }

    public static class Lion extends Cat {
    }

    public static class Bull extends Animal {
    }

    public static class Cow extends Animal {
    }

    public static class Animal {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При наличии иерархии типов сначало нужно сравнивать с более частным случаем и последовательно переходить к более общим, если совпадения не обнаружено. При наследовании вида Animal - Cat - Tiger, тигр будет являться и котом, и животным. Поэтому результат будет зависеть только лишь от порядка сравнения типов в вашем коде.

Answer (score 4):

Оператор instanceof проверяет возможность приведения объекта к заданному классу/интерфейсу, а не то что объект принадлежит к этому классу. Соответственно класс объекта корректнее будет определять через getClass().

```
public static String getObjectType(Object o) {
        if (o.getClass() == Cat.class) return "Кот";
        else if (o.getClass() == Tiger.class) return "Тигр";
        else if (o.getClass() == Lion.class) return "Лев";
        else if (o.getClass() == Bull.class) return "Бык";
        else if (o.getClass() == Cow.class) return "Корова";
        else return "Животное";
    }
```

Comment: ну я бы вот так не стал писать `else return` мало ли что)

Answer (score 3):

Если просто на пальцах, то когда вы пишете

```
public static class Tiger extends Cat {
}
```

Это значит, что класс данный класс принадлежит сразу двум типам: `Cat` и `Tiger`. То есть это и тигр и кот одновременно.
Далее у вас в методе первым делом проверяется, является ли объект котом? И да, для случая с тигром и львом вернется `true`, потому что они принадлежат типу кот.